# Why do I get the wrong HashCode from string?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, key, hashcode

I have this structure:

```
private HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Object,Integer>> commandList= new HashMap<>();
```

populated this way:

```
{1={1=2, 2=3, 3=4, -999=-999, -998=-998}}
```

from this code:

```
if ((msgTypeTemp=commandList.get(this.msgType).get(msgContent))==null) {
    Object s= "1";
    System.out.println("Class of s: "+s.getClass().getSimpleName()+"\nClass of msgContent: "+msgContent.getClass().getSimpleName());
    System.out.println("msgMap:\n"+msgMap);
    System.out.println("commandList:\n"+commandList);
    System.out.println(s.hashCode());
    System.out.println(msgContent.hashCode());
    System.out.println(commandList.get(this.msgType).get(s));
    this.msgType=JSockOS_UndefinedMsg.MSG_CODE;
    specialMsg=true;
} else {                
    this.msgType=msgTypeTemp;
    if (specialMsgType(this.msgType)){          
        specialMsg=true;
    }
}
```

My `HashMap` is generic type `<String,Integer>`

However, whenever I call the get method on `msgContent`, it comes out that instead of the hashcode of `"1"`, it was a hashcode which *until that moment* was set to 0, and which then changed after the get method call.

This happens only for calls that use `"msgContent"` parameter...

If I use this: `System.out.println(commandList.get(this.msgType).get(s));`

It returns "2" as expected...

Look also this image, it may help.

[image: Notice the differences in the two yellow boxes showed while debugging]

msgContent gets changed before the above code in this way:

it was first: 2.1.
then it gets: 1.

remaining a string.

```
msgContent=msgContent.toString().split(Pattern.quote("."))[1];
do(msgContent); // a methods which implements the code showed before.

//msgContent is a parameter, --> public void do(Object msgContent)
```

[EDIT]:
PROBLEM FOUND: msgContent is 495 chars... will fix its changes and update!

Comment: Are you sure the keys of internal `HashMap<Object,Integer>` are always of a same type? If not, the try to do that to avoid these problems. Remember that `new Integer(1)` won't return the same hashcode that `"1"`.

Comment: my hashmap will not have keys of same types but each key element will provide hashcode and equal methods to get right hashcode relative decisions.

in this example, my hashmap contains ONLY strings in the key value. In fact i tested this trying to get the value by key (String)"1".


msgContent is a String (at runtime) too, that contains "1", but it seems to be a different object...

Comment: In the image you posted, the details of `msgContent` are incomplete, seems like it's value is `"1 "` or something slightly different, which makes a huge difference.

Comment: i added details in my question, see the last rows... i show how msgContents gets modified before the get method call.

Comment: In short, you're not passing the same key, thus it's normal that you get a problem.

Comment: why? msgContent is a string with "1"... right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Strings are immutable, and `HashMap` uses `.equals()`, so it should be okay

Answer (score 1):

Even though `String` is immutable, the value of `hashCode` is [computed lazily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) for performance reasons, [as shown here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29):

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

As far as your actual problem is, are you entirely certain that your keys are `String`? The type you've provided there is `<Object, Integer>`, not `<String, Integer>`.

My test case works fine as shown here (this prints `elseSide`):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Object, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Object, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
    innerMap.put("1", 2);
    innerMap.put("2", 3);
    innerMap.put("-999",-999);
    innerMap.put("-998",-998);
    map.put(1, innerMap);

    int msgType = 1;
    String msgContent = "2.1";
    msgContent = msgContent.toString().split(Pattern.quote("."))[1];

    System.out.println(map);

    if(map.get(msgType).get(msgContent) == null) {
        System.out.println("ifSide");
    } else {
        System.out.println("elseSide");
    }
}
```

I think you should try adding the following debugging statements:

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> innerMap = commandList.get(this.msgType);
for(Map.Entry<Object, Integer> entry : innerMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("KeyClass: " + entry.getKey().getClass() + 
             "\tKeyValue:" + entry.getKey());
    // This will make sure the string doesn't have any unprintable characters
    if(entry.getKey() instanceof String) {
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("Key Length: " + key.getLength());
    }
}
```

I don't think your key in your inner map is actually a String, or perhaps the `String` somehow has unprintable characters. A hash of `630719471` is much too high for a one character `String`. It's also possible that `msgContent` has unprintable characters as well.

Comment: at the moment, i'm sure my hashmap will contain only <String,Integer> entries.

But i want to be free to add entries with different key types which will surely implement hashcode and equal methods.

Comment: Done, everything is STRING. 
"KeyClass: class java.lang.String KeyValue:1

KeyClass: class java.lang.String KeyValue:2

KeyClass: class java.lang.String KeyValue:3

KeyClass: class java.lang.String KeyValue:-999

KeyClass: class java.lang.String KeyValue:-998

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi See updated edit, I just thought of something

Comment: msgContent is 495 characters!

i'm going to debug until its initialization. Thanks for the advice!

will update soon!

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi If I've helped you, don't forget to click the checkmark below to the voting buttons next to my answer.